# Get uid from multiple database firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm stuck in my project's major problem.
What i want is: one user is customer, the other is driver.
I have 2 databases in which customer longitude and latitude is saving and also for driver in driver's database.
I  want when customer request driver application get the longitude and latitude of customer database under the `uid` of that current user which driver accepted.
How can I get the `uid` of that customer?
I've found method to access customer database

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId("<your application id>")
            .setApiKey("<your api key>")
            .setDatabaseUrl("<your DB url that ends in 'firebaseio.com/' ")
            .build();
```

But how can I get the uid of that current user which requested.
Here is image of 2 databases

[image: Firebase Database Customer]

[image: Firebase Database Driver]

Driver uid is just for suppose and I forgot to use `push()` method under uid.

Comment: i guess we can help, if u give the code that u have already written .

Answer (score 0):

```
myDatabase.child("codes")
     .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String clubkey = dataSnapshot.getKey();

firebase_instance.limit(100).on("child_added", function(snap) {
  var name = snap.key;
});
```

Comment: will you explain this?